# How to INNER JOIN a variable number of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table-valued function that returns the members of an AD group:

```
SELECT GroupName, MemberName FROM dbo.ShowMembers('AD Group Name')
```

I would like to be able to specify a few AD Group Names and perform an INNER JOIN on each of them to find the common members of all specified AD Group Names.

This works but if I have a number (2-6) of different AD groups to join, it would be easier to add them to a temporary table or variable:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ShowMembers ('Group1') m1, dbo.ShowMembers('Group2') m2
WHERE m1.MemberName = m2.MemberName
```

Comment: I would make a couple suggestions. First is to get in the habit of the "newer" style joins. Second, can you just use a cte as the main table of your query? It could contain the AD group names. Then do a cross apply to your ShowMember itvf and pass the group name from the cte or temp table.

Comment: thanks - and what is the "newer" style equivalent of this one?

Comment: I'm talking about using ANSI-92 style joins instead of the older ANSI-89 style like you posted. SELECT * FROM dbo.ShowMembers ('Group1') m1 join dbo.ShowMembers('Group2') m2 on m1.MemberName = m2.MemberName

Comment: I put newer in quotes because it was introduced over 25 years ago. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible you just have to change the way you go about it. Something like this would return the results from an unknown number of Groups and only return those that belong in each group.

```
with MyGroups as
(
    select 'Group1' as GroupName union all
    select 'Group2'
)

select g.GroupName
    , sm.MemberName
from MyGroups g
cross apply dbo.ShowMembers(g.GroupName) sm
group by g.GroupName
    , sm.MemberName
having COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) from MyGroups)
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally answered this is not possible. Dynamic SQL is always a solution for such problems.

Here, you probably should create an inline TVF or a view that you can use like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ShowMembers () m
WHERE m.MemberName IN (...) AND m.GroupName IN (...)
```

Something like this.